# Hibernate : Sorting ManyToMany mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, dbunit

Consider the following mapping with JPA annotations

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
@JoinTable(name = "infotype_validations", 
    joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "info_type_id") }, 
    inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "validation_id") }
)
@OrderBy(value="validation_id desc")
public Set<Validation> getValidation() {
    return validation;
}
```

My intention is to have a jointable in the database and each time the getValidation() is called in my services the records get returned ordered by validation_id.  Now to test my functionality I make use of DbUnit.  Each time I start a testclass my database gets created and hibernate creates my tables afterwhich DbUnit fills them with data.  When I comment @OrderBy my tests pass but when I uncomment it, I get table infotype_validations can't be found.  I've looked at the available documentation online and it seems it is perfectly possible to have @OrderBy in this kind of mapping.  So what am I missing ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the field name not the column name.

```
//Assuming the field is validationId
@OrderBy(value="validationId desc")
public Set<Validation> getValidation() {
    return validation;
}
```

Also make sure that the `infotype_validations` table exists within your database and the spelling matches.

Comment: argh right, I was to much focussing on the @joinColumn mapping that I forgot the obvious ...  thing is I inherit from a MappedSuperClass so all my Id columns are just the id property.  I wasn't sure if that was right to use to know on what table's id to sort ... all works now thnx

Comment: @kenny excellent stuff.  I cheated thought I checked one of my examples.  Best of luck.