# hibernate many-to-many mapping with orderby clause does not work

Tags: hibernate, many-to-many, sql-order-by

I have a question regarding the hibernate many-to-many mappings with the use of the @OrderBy annotation. Let's say we have table A, B and the glue table A_B. I want the collection A.bs be sorted by field B.date. When I run the query I get the exception saying:

```
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: ERROR: column b1_.date does not exist
```

The problem is that hibernate creates query that is searching for the column in the A_B table and not in the B table. I have been searching through the web and encountered the same question without a proper answer (https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=950032&sid=b7e3e9ff23a6da3b5fff2f5336d3bb1b) but at the same time issues dealing with similar problems and the answers were saying that such configuration is without a problem ([Hibernate : Sorting ManyToMany mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14294712/hibernate-sorting-manytomany-mapping#)). In the @OrderBy clause I tried using the field name in the domain object, column name in the DB but to no avail. Any progress in this issue? Any help or hints appreciated. Thx. :)

These are details:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="A")
public class A implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Set<B> bs = new HashSet<B>(0);

    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name="A_B", joinColumns = { 
        @JoinColumn(name="a_id", nullable=false, updatable=false) }, inverseJoinColumns = { 
        @JoinColumn(name="b_id", nullable=false, updatable=false) })
    @OrderBy(clause = "date desc")
    public Set<B> getBs() {
        return this.bs;
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name="B")
public class B implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Date date;

    /* setters and getters */
}
```

I omitted ids and other details. If I delete the @OrderBy annotation everything works like a charm.

More details about my getter on date:

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name="date", nullable=false, length=29)
public Date getDate() {
    return this.date;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code date isn't annotated by `@Column`.

It should looks like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="B")
public class B implements java.io.Serializable {

    @Column(name = "date")
    private Date date;

    /* setters and getters */
}
```

EDIT:

I create the same mapping and found problem.

You are using `org.hibernate.annotations.OrderBy`. With this annotation I have exactly the same problem.

Also normally I'm using `javax.persistence.OrderBy` and everything works fine.

So try mapping in that way:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name="A_B", joinColumns = { 
    @JoinColumn(name="a_id", nullable=false, updatable=false) }, inverseJoinColumns = { 
    @JoinColumn(name="b_id", nullable=false, updatable=false) })
@javax.persistence.OrderBy("date desc")
public Set<B> getBs() {
    return this.bs;
}
```

Comment: I have the @Column annotation at the getter method. That's how the hibernate tools reverse engineer the sources from DB:

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name="date", nullable=false, length=29)
    public Date getDate() {
        return this.date;
    }

Comment: I changed my answer. Check it now :D

Comment: Thx, it helped. :) Wouldn't manage to figure out such nuance myself. :)